# How to have negative indentation for stanzas or verses in `memoir`?

Tags: memoir, indentation, poetry

I use the `memoir` class for a children's poetry book. Some pages have background images and I would like to be able to move stanzas horizontally, to better adapt them to the graphical elements on the page. In some cases, I want to move a specific verse.

The documentation explains how to indent using `\indentpattern`, but I was only able to move text to the right, and I haven't found a way to move text to the left (i.e. have negative indentation).

In this example the verses of the first stanza flow around the right side of the 'A', I'd like to achieve something similar for the verses of the second stanza, such that they're on the left side of the shape.

If individual control over each verse is not possible, offsetting the whole stanza to the left would also be acceptable. How can this be accomplished with LaTeX?

[image: Text flowing around a shape]

This is the code I use for the example above:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}

\begin{document}

\PlainPoemTitle
\PoemTitle{Lo Remip Sumindentum}

\indentpattern{0123}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
\begin{patverse}
one two three four \\
one two three four \\
one two three four \\
one two three four.
\end{patverse}
\end{verse}

\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
six seven eight nine \\
six seven eight nine \\
six seven eight nine \\
six seven eight nine.
\end{verse}


\backgroundsetup{scale = 1,
angle = 0,
opacity = 1,
contents = {\includegraphics[
    width = \paperwidth,
    height = \paperheight]
    {example-image-a}}}
\BgThispage
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indentation can be controlled manually by adding negative `\hspace`:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}

\begin{document}

\PlainPoemTitle
\PoemTitle{Lo Remip Sumindentum}

\indentpattern{0123}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
\begin{patverse}
one two three four \\
one two three four \\
one two three four \\
one two three four.
\end{patverse}
\end{verse}

\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
\hspace{-50mm}six seven eight nine \\
\hspace{-53mm}six seven eight nine \\
\hspace{-56mm}six seven eight nine \\
\hspace{-59mm}six seven eight nine.
\end{verse}


\backgroundsetup{scale = 1,
angle = 0,
opacity = 1,
contents = {\includegraphics[
    width = \paperwidth,
    height = \paperheight]
    {example-image-a}}}
\BgThispage
\end{document}
```

[image: negative indentation]

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to apply a negative `\hspace` to the entire stanza and it had no effect, so I didn't even try it to apply it on each individual verse.